# ordem crescente:

Tags: python

Escreva um programa que leia três números inteiros a partir do teclado. Como saída, imprima os valores em ordem crescente. Bem de acordo com a questão tem que usar as funções min(a,b,c) e max(a,b,c).Exemplo de entrada 6,2,4 a Saída:2,4,6

Comment: Thiago, boa noite! Qual a dúvida? Abraço!

Comment: [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta)

Answer (score 1):

```
def funcao(a,b,c):
    valor = [ ] # lista iniciada
    valor.append(a) # < -- valor adicionado
    valor.append(b) # < -- valor adicionado
    valor.append(c) # < -- valor adicionado
    """Utilizado a func sort() com paramentro reverse False, ordena da maneira normal"""
    valor.sort(reverse=False)
    print("valores, crescente",valor)
    """Utilizado a func sort() com paramentro reverse True, inverte a ordem"""
    valor.sort(reverse=True)
    print("valores, decrescente", valor)


funcao( 6,2,4)

#No seu pedido de informação, descreveu que poderia ser 2 funções chamada min(... e max(...,
#ambas tem parametros ...(a,b,c), mas poderia usar função  Variádica.
#exemplo.
#max(*valores)
#min(*valores)
#Funções Variádica  permite adicionar infinidades de paramentros:
#max(39,29,12,192,1921,89,1,20)
#Antes de por em crescente e decrecente teria que converter o parametro para o tipo lista.
#Em resumo sua proposta é vaga , queria ajuda ou explicação?
#Mas caso queira criar 2 funções max e min é só adicionar o append.
```